# unit testing computed properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing

I'm currently trying to unit test a computed properties.

I have a fileOne.ts file :

```
export const fileOne = () => {
   
   const fx1 = computed ( () => { ... } );
   const fx2 = computed ( () => { ... } );
   const fx3 = computed ( () => { ... } );

}
```

this 'fileOne' is used in a Vue.vue aswell :

```
<template>
   ...
</template>

<script lang="ts">
   import { fileOne } from './fileOne';
   
   const fileOneState = fileOne( ... );

   ...
</script>
```

I want to unit test my computed properties of fileOne. At the moment i have a file named : 'fileOne.spec.ts' with :

```
describe('testing computed properties', () => {
  it('should return the right value', () => {
    expect().toBe();
  })
});
```

The problem is : I don't know what I need to import either how to get a instance with my computed properties to test.

I believe this is not clear but if someone understood, i'll be happy to have some helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't need to test the `computed` value, but extract the methods you are passing as arguments to `computed` and test those.

There is no need for unit testing to test the `computed` versions, but just your own business logic.

One of doing this is to either

- extract them to a new file and import them in both `fileOne.ts` and `fileOne.spec.ts` or
- export them from `fileOne.ts` and import them in `fileOne.spec.ts`.

I would go with option 1 as it clearly marks the fact that you are exporting some custom business logic and the fact that it ends up in a `computed` method is secondary. You can import that anywhere now.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer, i'll work on that